# UITableViewCell looks different at runtime than in InterfaceBuilder (on iPad)

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, uitableview

I am working on a universal app in swift. The fundament is a SplitViewController. The tableview is embedded in the detail view of the SplitViewController. My background color of the of UITableViewCells looks different than expected - but only on iPad. I tried the following settings:

TableView in Storyboard:
[image: TableView in Storyboard]

Hierarchy of the views:

[image: Hierarchy of the views]

Settings of the cell:

[image: Settings of the cell]

Settings of the content view:

[image: Settings of the content view]

Here is my code for "cellForRowAtIndexPath":

```
 let tableData = ["Test User 1", Test User 2"]

 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

         var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! UITableViewCell!

         cell.textLabel!.text  = tableData[indexPath.row]
         cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
         cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 

         return cell
     }
```

And the tableview looks in the simulator like this:

[image: simulator of tableview]

As mentioned - it looks right if I select an iPhone device as simulator. Here is a picture from the iPhone Simulator:
[image: iphone version of tableview]

I have no idea why it's white on the iPad and not dark gray as defined in the InterfaceBuilder (like on the iPhone)? Nothing is "selected" ..... I always used any/any as size class. I struggle here for days

I am happy for every hint.

Thanks in advance.
Daniel

Comment: post a picture when it runs on iPhone vs iPad

Comment: are you sure that the table view have cells on IPad maybe the white color is the tableview itself not the cells @myknack

Comment: Kindly check you UITableViewCell background color and cell contentView background color. May be you left this view background color

Comment: @Lamar see the updated post

Comment: @AbdAl-rhmanTaherBadary unfortunately not, both have the same code (dataSource). I just changed the simulator device. And as you can see on the picture there are two rows ... but the background is white :/

Comment: @bhanu, I have configured all color settings as you can see on the screenshots: background color of the view within the content view and background color of the view within the tableviewcell

Comment: Have you tried restating the background color in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method?

Comment: note guys - it is actually simply caused by a well-known Apple bug (the bug STILL seems to be there, 2016)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that generally there is (still) a **bug in Storyboard**, even in Xcode7,

you have to set the background color of cells **in code, it won't work from storyboard**

```
class YourCell:UITableViewCell
    {
    override func awakeFromNib()
        {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        }

    }
```

You may have another issue also, but this is one issue.